# Safest delimiter or convert from javascript hashmap to java linked map?

Tags: javascript, java

I have data like this, TITLE is the name of variable and below it is the string data (Please note the data can be different sometimes)

```
TITLE1
abcd
TITLE2
abcde
TITLE3
acd,sdssds!@#@$#$#%$%$^&**()aas
```

Now, I want to to send these three to java and want to make a linked map from them I did like this

```
JAVASCRIPT

var string  = "TITLE1=abcd, TITLE2=abcde, TITLE3=acd,sdssds!@#@$#$#%$%$^&**()aas"
```

and used it in java as

```
JAVA

    LinkedHashMap <String, String> selectedCheckBoxMap = new LinkedHashMap <String, String> ();
    String[] pairs = selectedCheckBoxTokens.split (",");

    for (int i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++)
    {
        String pair = pairs[i];
        String[] keyValue = pair.split ("=");
        selectedCheckBoxMap.put (keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
    }
```

But this breaks on "," as delimiter as TITLE3 already has character ','

I then used this character instead of "," as delimiter "‡", but this not a good approach.

What should I do  ? Should I change it to hashmap in javascript ? But how to convert hashmap from javascript to JAVA directly ? Or should I use some other delimiter ?

The delimiter should be character that we cannot type or ever come across in text.

Thanks,

Aiden

Comment: What about JSON ? How to use ? Any code example ?

Answer (score 0):

if your data is that regular you could split on a ", " instead.
if spaces are in your value sets, then you need to mark your data values... be that with single/double quotes or some other unique marker.

building a JSON object and then delivering it would likely be a more robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JSON:

```
var s = {};
s["TITLE1"] = "skladjdklsajdsla";
s["TITLE2"] = "*&^&^%&*,,()*&";
s["TITLE3"] = "acd,sdssds!@#@$#$#%$%$^&**()aas";
```

That code will create an Java Script Object:

```
Object { 
TITLE1="skladjdklsajdsla",  
TITLE2="*&^&^%&*,,()*&",  
TITLE3="acd,sdssds!@#@$#$#%$%$^&**()aas"
}
```

You can parse the Object using a JSON library for Java: 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html

See: [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

JSON Standard: http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 0):

When generating the string to be send, escape the commas and the equal signs in the values by replacing them with something else like %2C and %3D
Then or server side unescape by doing

```
selectedCheckBoxMap.put (keyValue[0], keyValue[1].replace("%2C",",").replace("%3D","="));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using common characters as a delimiter is error-prawn ever since. You have to escape each delimiter you use and then parse the string by yourself. This means, that you have to call `value.replace(/([\\=,])/g, '\\$1')` on each entry, before appending it to your datastring.

Even if i would recommend you using JSON, as Alzoid proposed, here is an untested implementation you could use to decode the input (assuming '\' is your escape character):

```
boolean escaped = false;
boolean waitingForKey = true;
String key = "";
String current = "";
for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
    char character = data.charAt(i);
    if (escaped) {
        current += character;
        escaped = false;
        continue;
    }

    if (waitingForKey && Character.isWhitespace(character)) {
        continue;
    } else if (waitingForKey) {
        waitingForKey = false;
    }

    switch (character) {
        case '\\':
            escaped = true;
            break;
        case '=':
            key = current;
            current = "";
            break;
        case ',':
            map.put(key, current);
            current = "";
            key = "";
            waitingForKey = true;
            break;
        default:
            current += character;
    }
}

if (!data.isEmpty()) {
    map.put(key, current);
}
```